# Localized drawable folder not always works

Tags: android, image, android-layout, drawable

Localized drawable folders works like this that phone searchs for a images in specific folder (in example **drawable-sw720p**) and if there is nothing it needs right now it searchs in normal **drawable** folder, right?

I have few images dedicated to tables. So, I need 4 drawable folders (**sw600dp**, **sw720dp**, **xxhdpi**, **xhdpi** also). And it should works fine, but - in these 4 folders I have the same image (multiplied by amount of different images), so in the end my app is a little bit too heavy.

Now my problem: some time ago I tested my other app on my friend's phone and I realized that his phone doesn't take images from **drawable** folder (it only takes images from it's folder like **drawable-mdpi**). So, I had to put all the images into **drawable-mdpi** and to others **drawables** event if some images are exactly the same.

So, now I want to minimalize my app size by putting all same events into the standard **drawable** folder and to **localized folders** only the ones which are different - but I'm scared of the situation I wrote about.

Is there any way to solve this problem? Or no and I just should copy the same images into every drawable folder I have?

Please let me know, I'm sure someone here knows the best practise to make it lighter and works just fine on all the phones (including dumb ones like my friend's) ;)

Comment: What you mean by localized  folder in terms of drawable?

Comment: I mean folder drawable-mdpi is used for phones with medium density pixels, drawable-sw720p for 10' tables etc.

Comment: Some times it happens but i don't think so there is requirement to add image in each folder because that will insincere app size you can add drawable-hdpi and drawable-large this is it or only one folder is enough drawable-nodpi

Comment: So rather than making 4 (xdpi, xxdpi, sw720dp, sw600dp) 1 (-large) should be enough? I'll try, thanks :)

Comment: yes drawable-hdpi and drawable-large its enough.